# Angular-meteor slick-carousel causes JQuery to load twice

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meteor, npm, angular-meteor

I'm using Angular-meteor for a project right now and I had a question about using NPM. I'm using a specific library (slick-carousel... and also angular-slick-carousel), and when I install it via npm and then attempt to use it in my app, I get jquery defined twice in my modules.js file that was put together by meteor I'm assuming. So I get JQuery defined once before slick-carousel (perfect). Then it gets defined again after slick-carousel, causing the $.fn.slick function that was registered to be wiped out. I think it's including jquery again, because the slick-carousel node package comes with the node_modules folder containing jquery, causing it to load again.

This causes the following to happen:

`modules.js?hash=96df622…:14632 TypeError: slickness.not(...).slick is not a function`

What's the easiest way to set this up, so jQuery only gets loaded once, and before slick-carousel? I imagine there's a pretty easy way to let the packager know the dependency order here, but I'm pretty new to this whole ecosystem still.

Comment: When you say modules.js, do you mean .meteor/packages? Meteor includes jquery by default, as does Angular. It's quite likely that you are including 2 different versions of jquery, most likely through a package dependency in one of the node_modules/*/package.json files. If a package has a dependency on a specific version, you can install that version and it may fix the problem for you

Answer (score 0):

Rather than importing the entire slick-carousel dependency, only import the files you need.

For example, 
        import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"; 
and 
        import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.js";

Simply don't import the node_modules directory of slick-carousel that includes the duplicate jquery files.